# Please check my proof that the union of a collection of connected subsets is connected

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

The problem reads:

> Let $\{ E_j : j\in J \}$ be a collection of connected subsets of a metric space $X$ such that $E_i \cap E_j \neq \emptyset$ for every $i,j\in J$.  Prove that $\cup _{j\in J} E_j$ is connected.

**Before marking this a duplicate**, please consider that I am aware that there are a number of problems similar to this on this site, but all of them that I've found state that $\cap _{j\in J} E_j \neq \emptyset$, which is not the same as this problem.  That being said, here is my attempt at a proof:

---

Defining $E=\cup _{j\in J} E_j$, suppose $E=A\cup B$, where $A$ and $B$ are separated and nonempty.

Since $E_j$ is connected, $\forall j \in J$, either $E_j \subset A$ or $E_j \subset B$.  (What I am trying to say here is that since each subset is itself connected, you cannot split a subset so that one part is in $A$ and the other part is in $B$.)

WLOG, let $K \subset J: B= \cup _{k\in K} E_k$ and $A= \cup _{i\in J\setminus K}E_i$.

But $\forall E_i, E_j: \exists x_{ik} \in E_i\cap E_j$ (which, by definition, is not empty).

$\Rightarrow x_{ik} \in A\cap B$

But $A\cap B = \emptyset$, which is a contradiction.

$\therefore A$  or $B$ must be empty

$\Rightarrow E$ is connected. $\square$

Comment: what is $E$ ? I could guess but you never defined it. Assuming $E=\cup _{j\in J} E_j$, the proof is not quite complete, unless you also specify that $i\in K$ and $j\in J\setminus K$. Do not have to say "$\forall$", rather say, since $B$ is non-empty, there is $i$ such that $E_i\subset B$, and since $A$ is non-empty there is $j$ with $E_j\subset A$, etc. The way you say it it is not clear if perhaps both $E_i,E_j$ are contained in say $A$ (sometimes they will be, but you have to pick them carefully, so one is in $A$ the other is in $B$).

Comment: @Mirko: You are correct about $E$.  Sorry, I'll edit the question.  Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your proof is correct. But you may simplify the latter bit. So you've already shown that either $E_j \subset A$ or $E_j \subset B$ for all $j \in J$. WLOG say $E_k \subset A$ for some $k$. As $E_j \cap E_k \neq \emptyset$ for all $j \in J$, we must have $E_j \subset A$ for all $j \in J$. Hence $\bigcap_{j \in J} E_j \subset A$ and so $B = \emptyset$.

Comment: That does make it way simpler.  The part about $K$ was what worried me most, and this avoids it, so this is great!  Thanks!